# 0x%016llX from C to python?

Tags: python, c, type-conversion, data-conversion

I am using the following expression in C code:

`sprintf(message, "0x%016llX; ", someIntValue);`

How do I do the same in python?

I know in C what it means.

1. the mandatory % character
2. a 0 flag for padding
3. the 16 as "minimum field width"
4. the ll as "length modifiers"
5. the x conversion specifier

What I don't know, is how to do it in python...

Comment: http://pyformat.info

Comment: Have you searched "String formatting python"?

Comment: Don't ask to translate, ask what something does, or ask for what you want ("I want the hex stringification of an integer, padded to 16 digits. In C, I would have used ...")

Comment: `someIntValue` as an `int` is a problem.  Fix by using `someUnsignedLongLongValue` and an `unsigned long long`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same can be achieved using either of the following:

```py
"0x%016X; " % someIntValue            # Old style
```

```py
"{:016X}; ".format( someIntValue )    # New style
```